# Subquery return more than 1 row MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
delete from departments
where department_id = (select department_id
                       from employees
                       where salary > 100000);
```

The query of course return more than 1 row, someone know how can I delete all the departments in just one query without do a function or something like that?

Comment: I really, really hope, for your sake, that the delete statement fails due to a foreign key constraint violation. If it does not you will end up with employees with a `department_id` that does not match a record in the `department` table. [Example of orphan record on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4fe6b/1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively join them

```
DELETE d
FROM departments d
INNER JOIN employees e ON d.department_id = e.department_id
WHERE e.salary > 100000;
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `IN`:

```
delete from departments 
where department_id in (select department_id 
                        from employees 
                        where salary > 100000);
```